# Example from cppreference.com does not compile with MSVC

Tags: c++, c++20

Tried to compile the following example from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines):

```
#include <coroutine>

struct promise;
struct coroutine : std::coroutine_handle<promise>
{
    using promise_type = struct promise;
};

struct promise {
    coroutine get_return_object()
    {
        return { coroutine::from_promise(*this) };
    }
    std::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_void() {}
    void unhandled_exception() {}
};

struct S {
    int i;
    coroutine f() {
        std::cout << i;
        co_return;
    }
};
```

but got compiler error:

```
error C3789: this function cannot be a coroutine: 'coroutine::promise' does not declare the member 'get_return_object()'
```

Compiler: MSVC2019, /std:c++latest

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30137 for x86

But GCC12 compiles it, what is wrong with MSVC?

**EDIT1**

The same error with MSVC2022

Optimizing Compiler Version 19.30.30709 for x86

/std:c++latest

Comment: cppreference likes to be up on the latest version of the standard — even if no compiler yet supports that standard.

Answer (score 3):

As the Site says:

**Work in progress:** This page is in progress of being updated to reflect the parts of Coroutines Technical Specification that were included in the working draft of C++20.

This example is not runnable with a MSVC2019 Compiler.
You can install and try it with this version:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes

Comment: The same error with MSVC2022

Comment: Did you set the cpp standard in your project settings to 2020?

Comment: I knew that you will ask, see EDIT1

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the problem in question and managed to solve it.

The thing that made me suspicious initially was the form of

```cpp
struct promise;
struct coroutine : std::coroutine_handle<promise>
{
    using promise_type = struct promise;
};
```

because `struct promise` in the `using` declaration is itself a valid standalone forward declaration. The error is complaining about `promise` not declaring its member functions, which indicates that the `struct promise` in the `coroutine` struct is shadowing the global `struct promise` that we forward-declared and later define to contain the allegedly absent member functions.

Evidently GCC decided to identify these types, while MSVC did not.

I changed the `using` statement to simply be

```cpp
using promise_type = promise;
```

and got a new error:

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'promise'
```

this one doesn't tell us much, but IntelliSense further reports that:

```
E0757 function "std::coroutine_handle<_Promise>::promise [with _Promise=promise]" is not a type name
```

which led me to realize that `promise` in my new `using` declaration was being confused for the `std::coroutine_handle<T>::promise()` member function of the handle type. I fixed this by explicitly qualifying `promise` with `::promise` to indicate that it comes from the global namespace, like so:

```cpp
struct promise;
struct coroutine : std::coroutine_handle<promise>
{
    using promise_type = ::promise;
};
```

which solves this ambiguity and prevents the compiler from confusing `::promise` with the parent class's member function. While this isn't the source of your original error, I suspect it's the reason why the example was changed from simply `using promise_type = promise;` into a forward declaration, which fixed the `coroutine`-internal naming collision in exchange for a namespace/scoping issue. Using the explicitly-qualified `::promise` for the `using` statement solves both of these problems.

I'm not sure why GCC allows the cppreference version to compile since it seems to me that the global `struct promise;` and the `struct promise` declared within `coroutine` should be distinct types, but I may be misunderstanding the situation.